# Android Application Retrofit

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, retrofit, android-application-class

I'm creating a simple application that will process the request using retrofit library.

First I'm initialize retrofit

Here's my MyApplication.java class

```
@Override
public void onCreate ()
{
    super.onCreate();

    Hawk.init(getApplicationContext()).build();
    sApp = this;
    mAPIService = RetrofitServiceFactory.createService(APIService.class, this);
}
```

I'm Calling this class

RetrofitServiceFactory.java

```
public static <S> S createService (Class<S> serviceClass, Context context)
{
    final String authHeader;
    PrefManager prefManager = new PrefManager(context);
    if (prefManager.getAppUserToken() != null)
    {
        authHeader = "Bearer " + prefManager.getAppUserToken();
    }
    else
    {
        authHeader = "";
    }

    httpClient.addInterceptor(new ResponseInterceptor());
    httpClient.addInterceptor(new ChuckInterceptor(context));
    //add authorization header
    httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor()
    {
        @Override
        public Response intercept (Chain chain) throws IOException
        {
            Request lOriginalRequest = chain.request();
            Request lRequest = lOriginalRequest.newBuilder().header("Authorization", authHeader)
                    .method(lOriginalRequest.method(), lOriginalRequest.body()).build();

            return chain.proceed(lRequest);
        }
    });

    OkHttpClient lClient = httpClient.build();
    sRetrofit = sBuilder.client(lClient).build();
    return sRetrofit.create(serviceClass);
}
```

But why I'm never getting the token from sharedpreferences after I logged in. At least I need to re-open the application?
thanks and sorry for my English xD

Comment: could you please add the code instead of posting links to censored screenshots? there really is nothing you would have to worry about, that someone could ever use as a technological advance.

Comment: ah sorry, ok it was updated

Comment: I'm not sure but instead of passing "this" , try " MyApplication.this"  and while saving it to sharedpreferences check whether it is saved or not ?

Comment: Android Application run on first time the app launch right? because it happen when im trying to use login activity and after that i think it was saved to the shared preferences, but retrofit just done build the builder. how to "rebuild" them?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? "But why I'm never getting the token from sharedpreferences after I logged in." is unclear.

Comment: @AnshulVerma it was saved, but when im use it on retrofit service class always return null